# How to protect metrics, livenessprobe and readinessprobe endpoints in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, nginx-ingress

I have a kubernetes deployment which provides liveness, readiness and metrics endpoints. Via a nginx-ingress and service the deployment is advertised to the public web.

My questions is what is the best way to protect these probe endpoints so that they are available for kubernetes and prometheus but not outside the cluster.

Possibilities to handle that which I found are:

- adding server / config snippets via annotations to the ingress config which block access to the specific paths
- running the probes/endpoints on another port (not an option for me)
- using specific httpHeaders (tokens, etc)

Are there any other solutions?
Is there a best practice way to handle the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why would you advertise the probes to the web. Those should be only available from the cluster network. Can you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score -1):

One option is to expose /metrics, liveness and readiness probe endpoints to a different HTTP port that will not be accessible outside of the the cluster. You only map the container port to the outside world. Here is an example.
https://github.com/slok/go-http-metrics/blob/master/examples/gorilla/main.go#L53